# On minimal coupling in Coulomb gauge

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian, commutator, semiclassical

The Hamiltonian for a non-relativistic particle in a uniform external magnetic field is given  in its simplest form by:
$$
\mathcal{H} = \frac{\left|\mathbf{\hat{p}}-\frac{q}{c}\mathbf{\hat{A}}\right|^2}{2m}+V(\mathbf{r})
$$
Now, using the condition $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{\hat A}=0\ $ (commonly known as *Coulomb gauge*):

$$
\require{cancel}
\begin{aligned}
\left|\mathbf{\hat{p}}-\frac{q}{c}\mathbf{\hat{A}}\right|^2 &= \left(\mathbf{\hat{p}}-\frac{q}{c}\mathbf{\hat{A}}\right)\cdot\left(\mathbf{\hat{p}}-\frac{q}{c}\mathbf{\hat{A}}\right) &&\\ 
&= \hat p ^2 + \left(\frac q c \right){\hat A}^2 + {i\hbar}\frac{q}{c}\left(\cancel{\nabla\cdot\mathbf{\hat{A}}}+\mathbf{\hat{A}}\cdot\nabla\right) =\hat p ^2 + \left(\frac q c \right)^2{\hat A}^2 + {i\hbar}\frac{q}{c}\left(\mathbf{\hat{A}}\cdot\nabla\right)
\end{aligned}
$$
but that's **not** the right answer. The third term should be $\displaystyle 2{i\hbar}\frac{q}{c}\left(\mathbf{\hat{A}}\cdot\nabla\right)$ instead.

What's wrong with this simple calculation?

Comment: Do the calculation by acting the Hamiltonian on a function.

Comment: Indeed, my professor used a test function $f$... but I don't understand where is the difference, since the final result does not depend on $f$, as it's expected.

Comment: Do it with a test function. Then do it without. Carefully compare each calculation term by term. Is there a term you get on one side that isn’t there on the other side?

Comment: Ok, here's the culprit: $(\mathbf{p}\cdot \mathbf{A}-\mathbf{A}\cdot\mathbf{p})f=\mathbf{p}\cdot(\mathbf{A}f)-\mathbf{A}\cdot(\mathbf{p}f)$. But is it general? I mean.. it's not obvious that $\mathbf{p}\cdot \mathbf{A}f$ *has to be* interpreted as $\mathbf{p}\cdot(\mathbf{A}f)$ and *not* as $(\mathbf{p}\cdot\mathbf{A})f$.

Comment: It’s standard convention so it does have to interpreted in exactly that way.

Comment: I added an answer note that your problem is even more fundamental. The well known relation is $[x,P_x]=i\hbar$ but if you do it naively: $xP_x-P_x x= - i \hbar x \partial_x - (- i  \hbar\partial_x x)= i \hbar ( -x\partial x+ 1     )\neq i \hbar$. This is wrong, you have to add a test function to get the right result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make this calculations, I usually use commutators and the relations between the position operator $\mathbf X $ and the mometum operator $\mathbf P$ that is
$$[X_i,P_j]=\mathrm i \hbar \delta_{i,j}\tag1$$.

Thus, we can expand

$$|\mathbf P + \mathbf A |^2= P^2 +\mathbf P \cdot \mathbf A + \mathbf A \cdot \mathbf P + A^2=\sum_{i=1}^3\left( P_iP_i + A_iP_i+P_iA_i +A_iA_i\right)=$$

$$\sum_{i=1}^3\left(P_iP_i+ 2A_iP_i+[P_i,A_i]+A_iA_i \right)$$

If  the operators $A=A_i(\mathbf X)$ (function that depends only on position), then you can use equation (1) to show that $[P_i,A_i(\mathbf X)]=-\mathrm i \hbar \partial_i (A_i) =-\mathrm i \hbar (\nabla \mathbf \cdot A )$.

Note that your problem also applies to equation (1).